# Selenium IDE Fancy Select not working

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm trying to select from a fancy select drop down menu, but for some reason i can't get the value to change. I've tried recording clicks, using the xpath with the click command, and now I'm trying to use the select command. None seem to work. Has anyone else encountered this/have any ideas about how to change the value of a fancy select?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a select step defined, select (or selectAndWait) would be the Command, xpath=(your xpath) would be the Target, and the item you wish to select from the option list would be the Value.  The Value can also be the index of the item in the list, where the topmost entry can be referenced by placing a index=0 as the Value:

```
select | xpath=[YourSelectElementXPATH] | ValueFromTheList
```

or

```
select | xpath=[YourSelectElementXPATH] | index=1
```

If you are able to include your step or the URL to the page in question, more specific assistance can be provided.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I've tried this but I keep getting this error: [error] Specified element is not a Select (has no options). However, I am pretty sure it is indeed a select. Does that give u any ideas?

Comment: Hi Sean,  If you look at the HTML Source for that control, what does it show?